# Android Widget Prev and Next not working

Tags: android, android-widget

i'm creating widget for my project. In that widget Prev and Next button is available. 
In Same widget create two times in homepage. If I click prev for 1st widget 2nd also changing. I don't want to change another one.

my code:

```
Intent WidgetIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateService.class);
PendingIntent NextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, WidgetIntent.putExtra("dir", 1), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
WidgetIntent.setData(Data);
WidgetIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

Intent PrevIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateService.class);
PrevIntent.setData(Data);
PrevIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
PendingIntent PrevPIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 2, PrevIntent.putExtra("dir", -1), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

If anyone know share here.

thanks,

Comment: Have a look at my answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551679/how-to-know-clicked-widget-id/15557194#15557194

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer here
[How to know clicked widget id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551679/how-to-know-clicked-widget-id/15557194#15557194)

Comment: Hi in my project onReceive method not using, if I use also click event happening both widget. one widget opened two times if I click 1st 2nd also changing.

Comment: If I got you right you have two instances of the same app widget on your home screen. They will always behave identical unless you take care to handle click events individually. To do so you can use the pattern shown in my code. You need an individual intend per widget and handle this in OnReceive.